# ¿Como crear un id de tipo incremental con zerofill?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo una duda como puedo realizar un **zerofill** utilizando **laravel** 5.5 en **eloquent** en mis migraciones, la verdad he revisado la documentación y no he observado ningún parámetro que se pueda pasar a mi columna para simular este comportamiento, en realidad necesito un id que comience de la siguiente forma: **0001**, **0002**, **0003**, en mi indice incremental, estoy utilizando **postgres** como base de datos.

```
introducir el código aquí
Schema::create('hospital', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->integer('reference')->length(2)->zerofill(000);
});
```

Pensé en algo parecido  a lo anterior pero esto no existe en **laravel** o amenos eso he encontrado. Si alguien puede ayudarme le agradecería demasiado con una explicación detallada de una posible solución, ya que he también escuchado algo sobre uso de **mutators** con los modelos pero nunca los he utilizado.

Comment: Siempre serán 3 cero al inicio?

Comment: si mi amigo necesito 3 ceros pero pues la idea es que si se necesita ampliar puedan ser siempre digamos 3, o 5 pero siempre tendrá la misma cantidad de ceros.

Comment: Entiendo mi amigo, pero en realidad no he trabajado con los mutators, ni con los triggers en estos momentos lo único que necesitaría seria crear una columna de tipo autoincrement con zerofill

Answer (score 1):

Si no afecta en tu flujo de trabajo, puedes asignar esta tarea a un *accessor* que te ayude a

- formatear la salida de los datos (sería lo mas conveniente, ya que no es correcto estar manipulando la estructura de la base de datos de un momento a otro para la salida que se espera que tengan los datos)
- Preserva la estructura original de tu tabla y su información
- No afecta los datos ya almacenados dado que mencionas que podrían ser 3 o 5 cifras de cero
- Lo mantienes a nivel del framework con lo cual la solución se programa
- Deberás considerar usar el modelo para que dicho método sea invocado
- El nombre del método debe incluir el nombre de la propiedad a recuperar
- Retornas por dentro del método el valor obtenido y a ese mismo le asignas una concatenación de lo que deseas mostrar

Tu código debería verse así dentro del model `TuModelo.php`

```
public function getIdAttribute($value)
{
    return "000".$value;
}
```

Con un resultado parecido a esto:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "name": "uno",
        "email": "mail@mail.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2020-03-12 05:14:07",
        "password": "scret",
        "remember_token": null,
        "created_at": "2020-03-12T05:14:07.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-12T05:14:07.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "name": "dos",
        "email": "mail1@mail.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2020-03-12 05:16:10",
        "password": "scret",
        "remember_token": null,
        "created_at": "2020-03-12T05:16:10.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-12T05:16:10.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "0003",
        "name": "tres",
        "email": "mail2@mail.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2020-03-12 05:27:25",
        "password": "scret",
        "remember_token": null,
        "created_at": "2020-03-12T05:27:25.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-12T05:27:25.000000Z"
    }
]
```

**Referencias**

- [Accessors en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)